# ¿Como puedo accionar una cerradura electrica de 24V con Arduino?

Tags: arduino, nfc

Tengo un circuito en la que conecto un Arduino a una Shield NFC y ésta a una protoboard. Mi objetivo es que se accione una cerradura eléctrica que funciona con 10-24V en AC y en DC, para ello he colocado un transistor 2N2222 y una resistencia de 330 Ohmios.

El problema que tengo es que cuando conecto la placa protoboard a la cerradura, se enciende el LED, pero la cerradura esta inmóvil.

Éste es el esquema en el cual me he basado para montar todo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y ésta es la imagen de como lo tengo yo armado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por último tengo el código que estoy utilizando:

```
#include <PN532.h>
#include <SPI.h>

/*Chip select pin can be connected to D10 or D9 which is hareware optional*/
/*if you the version of NFC Shield from SeeedStudio is v2.0.*/
#define PN532_CS 10
PN532 nfc(PN532_CS);
#define  NFC_DEMO_DEBUG 1

const int control = 7 ;
const int speed = 200;

void setup(void) {
pinMode(control,  OUTPUT) ;}


void loop(void) {
digitalWrite(control, HIGH);
     delay(2000);
     digitalWrite(control, LOW);
     delay(1000);
}
```

Gracias de antemano,
Saludos.

Comment: A ver si te he entendido. ¿ Quieres hacer funcionar una cerradura que **necesita un mínimo de 10V** sumistrándole corriente desde Arduino, que **solo proporciona 5V** ?

Comment: Eso es, solo que en mi caso tengo el transistor 2N2222, para que el arduino que solo proporciona 5V, lo amplie a mas de 10V. Asi que no se si se trata de que no lo tengo bien alimentado, o conectado.

Comment: De electrónica se *lo básico*, pero, si multiplicas el voltaje, **divides** la intensidad. ¿ Tu fuente de alimentación proporciona la intensidad necesaria, teniendo en cuenta el transistor ?

Comment: ¿Podrías compartir el esquema que incluya la fuente de alimentación, la tensión que proporciona, y cómo obtienes también la tensión con la que alimentas al arduino? Veo que estás sacando el voltaje de la toma +5 del arduino, y esa siempre va a dar +5v aunque le alimentes con mayor tensión.

Comment: Y si solo va a mandar +5V, ¿Como podría amplificarla a mas de +10V? Por otro lado, he encontrado un adaptador que va a la corriente con un cable de alimentacion al Arduino, y manda +15V. El led se ilumina con mucha mas intensidad que antes, pero la cerradura sigue sin reaccionar.

Comment: Lo mas simple: utiliza un [relé](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rel%C3%A9).

Comment: @YueNecrosano, recuerda que debes nombrar (con un @ delante) a las personas que te responden para que les llegue una notificación y sepan que le has respondido. El problema está en que estás conectando la cerradura al conector de `+5` y no a `Vin`. ¿Qué requerimientos de corriente tiene la cerradura? Si no los conoces usa un polímetro.

Answer (score 1):

No has puesto el diagrama, pero en la foto tu 2N222 está conectado directamente al Arduino, que sólo produce 5V.

El 2N222 no está amplificando nada, simplemente actúa como switch 0-5V.

Si quieres amplificar el voltaje, tienes que sacar 10V (o más volts) de otra parte, con una segunda fuente de poder,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Recuerda conectar GND de Arduino con GND de la segunda fuente de voltaje.

Una alternativa mejor sería usar conectar Arduino a un relay. De esa manera aislas electricamente el Arduino de los voltajes altos requeridos por la cerradura, asi:

[image: Arduino activando aplicación de 220V]

Relays de 5VC de entrada, capaces de manejar 10A a 250V AC estan a menos de medio euro en Aliexpress.

Comment: +1 por el relay y la fuente externa. Hacer pasar tanta intensidad por un arduino **NO** es buena idea en absoluto.

Answer (score -1):

Seguramente lo que te pasa es que a la cerradura eléctrica le falte potencia.

Esto sucede porque el propio Arduino solo produce como mucho 5V si tu cerradura es de 24V es imposible que actué porque no llegue ni a la mitad de potencia necesaria.

Lo que te recomiendo es que compres un relé que lo que hace es que puedas tener código y tengas mas potencia (si no tienes mucha experiencia con el relé te recomiendo que te compres un modulo de relé que por Amazon es bastante barato y muy fácil de usar)

[image: Rele]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta pregunta ya tiene respuesta. Tu respuesta es incompleta y no agrega nada de valor.