# ¿Como mandar una señal continua con arduino?

Tags: arduino, nfc

Buenas! Tengo una cerradura electrónica que esta conectada a una protoboard y esta a una shield NFC con un Arduino.
Consigo mandarle señal y que la cerradura se accione, pero solo por medio segundo después de conectarla, es decir, junto los cables a la cerradura y al hacer contacto se acciona medio segundo y se para, si quiero volver a accionarla tengo que quitarle los cables y volver a conectarlos nuevamente, y así todo el rato.

Me gustaría saber si es posible estar mandando la señal de forma continua y sin interrupciones, que si están los cables conectados este la cerradura continuamente accionada.

Adjunto las especificaciones de la cerradura en cuestion:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es mi código:

```
#include <PN532.h>
#include <SPI.h>

#define PN532_CS 10
PN532 nfc(PN532_CS);
#define  NFC_DEMO_DEBUG 1

const int control = 9 ; 

void setup(){

 pinMode(control,  OUTPUT) ;

}

void loop(){

 digitalWrite(control, HIGH);

}
```

Gracias de antemano,
Saludos.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como puedo accionar una cerradura electrica de 24V con Arduino?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/70170/como-puedo-accionar-una-cerradura-electrica-de-24v-con-arduino) **del mismo usuario, @YueNecrosano**.

Comment: Creo que has vuelto a publicar la misma pregunta que antes pero con el código. ¿Podrías agregar este código a tu pregunta anterior? -- *¿Qué requerimientos de tensión e intensidad tiene esa cerradura? ¿Cuál es tu código completo? ¿Qué significa "junto los cables a la cerradura"? ¿Los cortocircuitas o los conectas a otro lado o al arduino? ¿Podrías ser un poco más específico con lo que te ocurre? Gracias.*

Comment: En la ultima pregunta que hice fue para lograr que la cerradura le llegara corriente eléctrica (cosa que al final logre realizar). Ahora que le llega se me presenta otro problema, que es el que he planteado anteriormente. La cerradura tiene 2 tomas por la que le llega la corriente eléctrica, asi que cuando conecto los cables de la protoboard a ella, esta solo se acciona medio segundo, asi que tengo que quitarlos de las dos tomas de corriente y volverlos a conectar para que se vuelva a accionar medio segundo mas.

Comment: ¿Podrías proporcionarnos un enlace a las características de la cerradura? ¿Cómo has terminado montando el circuito que alimenta la cerradura? Suena a efecto de algún condensador de acople o a que la cerradura es de AC.

Comment: El circuito lo he montado de la manera que describí en la ultima pregunta, resultaba que solo tenia que recolocar los cables en los pines del Arduino. Ya he añadido la información correspondiente a la cerradura. Gracias.

Comment: Es probable (según las características puede hacerse con sólo DC, pero luego hacia de corriente alterna) que la cerradura necesite un pulso oscilante y no constante para funcionar. También puede ser que sea el transistor (eso no puedo comprobarlo ahora pq estoy fuera). Prueba a enviarle un pulso PWM de 50-60 Hz para comprobar si su respuesta mejora. PD: quizá necesites un diodo (en inversa entre + y - de la cerradura) para derivar a tierra los pulsos inversos de la bobina.

Comment: Me parece que el duplicado, es un "relacionado".

Comment: He probado enviándole un   analogWrite(control, 255), pero no ha dado resultado. Incluso he probado a suministrarle mayor corriente eléctrica, pero tampoco funciono.